# WxWidgets - wxlistbox - store more then string

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Can I store more informations in `wxListBox` than just a string?

I would like to store there objects (from one class), is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxListBox`, like many other controls, has the concept of "client data" i.e. arbitrary pointer that can be associated with each item. I don't recommended to use it however, it is usually better to just maintain the objects separately in a `std::vector<>`, just as you already do, judging from your other questions. This won't happen automatically however, you will need to update both the listbox and the vector when you insert/delete/update items.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a wxListCtrl has a user data element that can be assigned which may serve what you want but i believe that this approach is overly complicated.  I have always found it to be sufficient to maintain a container of objects (generally a std::vector or std::deque) and then to use the selected item index to index into this container.

Comment: Summing up: Should I use std::vector and connect it with wxListBox?